# flowplayer: pause/stop all running players when new video is run

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I have multiple instances of flowplayer on a page, is there a way to stop/pause any running video from playing when another one is started?

I'd like to only ever one video to play at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out it's possible so it was my bad code that screwed it up ;-)

http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/installation/multiple-players.html

Comment: PS: The secret is that the a-tag is not allowed to be empty.